# Confusion with splat operator and Range in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I was trying to see how splat operator worked with `range` in Ruby. To do so ran the below code in my IRB:

```
*a = (1..8)
#=> 1..8
```

When the above is fine, what happened with below? means why a gives `[]`?

```
*a,b = (1..8)
#=> 1..8
b
#=> 1..8
a
#=> []
```

means why `b` gives []?

```
a,*b = (1..8)
#=> 1..8
a
#=> 1..8
b
#=> []
```

What precedence took place in the below `Rvalues` ?

```
 a,*b = *(2..8),*3,*5
# => [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 5]
 b
# => [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 5]
 a
# => 2
```

Here is another try to the splat operator(*) :-

While I know that in parallel assignment we couldn't use multiple splatted variable, but why not the same when splat is used with `Rvalues`?

```
 *a,*b = [1,2,3,4,5]
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected tSTAR
*a,*b = [1,2,3,4,5]
    ^
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

The above is as expected.

```
 a = *2,*3,*5
#=> [2, 3, 5]
```

But couldn't understand the above.

Comment: Interestingly, as long as RHS is an Array, it seems to work. (`*a,b = (1..8).to_a` or `*a,b = *(1..8)`). Also, `a = *2,*3,*5` is same as `a = 2,3,5`

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093513/how-exactly-does-the-ruby-splat-operator-get-the-first-and-rest-of-an-array-duri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think of parallel assignment as setting an array of variables equal to another array with pattern matching.

One point is that a range is a single value until you convert it to an array or splat it. For instance `[1..5]` which is a one element array of the range `1..5` and not `[1,2,3,4,5]`. To get the array of ints you need to do `(1..5).to_a` or `[*(1..5)]`

---

The first one i think is the trickiest. If the splatted var is assigned to one element, the var itself must be a one-element array:

```
*a = 5
a 
# => [ 5 ]
```

For the next two, splat takes 0 or more not already assigned values into an array. So the following makes sense:

```
*a, b = (1..8)
```

is like

```
*a, b = "hey"
```

which is like

```
*a, b = [ "hey" ]
```

so `*a` is `[]` and `b` is `"hey"` and by the same logic that if `*a` is nothing, `a` must be an empty array. Same idea for

```
a, *b = (1..5)
```

For the next one, the range is splatted, so the assignment makes a lot of sense again:

```
[*(2..4), 9, 5]
# => [2, 3, 4, 9, 5]
```

And parallel assignment with a splat again. Next one is similar:

```
[*3, *4, *5]
# => [3, 4, 5]
```

So that's like

```
a = 3, 4, 5
```

which is like

```
a = [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: +1. for the experiments. "To get the array of ints you need to do (1..5).to_a or [*(1..5)]". Actually `*1..5` will do.

Comment: My bad - `*a, b = (1..8)` couldn't understand the logic.

Answer (score 1):

`splat` has a very low precedence, almost anything will be executed earlier than the splat.
The code is splatting but the result is thrown away: `b = *a = (1..8); p b #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`